# Disk Utility with extra Mac HD after clean install on Monterey (formerly Big Sur)

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, install, monterey, disk-format

Not sure if I need to re-format and re-install again.

Is it normal to see so many Mac HD, and should I try to remove the extra ones?

Had some HD issue where somehow there was no space left and thus there was nothing to do but to clean install everything.

Now it seems there are multiple Mac HD / Mac HD - Data, with different avail space, as shown:

[image]

[image]

```
 ~ % diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         850.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data ⁨BOOTCAMP⁩                150.2 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +850.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     688.1 KB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 271.6 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.1 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     66.9 GB    disk1s5
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            15.7 GB    disk1s7
   7:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.7 GB    disk1s7s1

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        +455.4 MB   disk2
   1:        Apple_partition_map ⁨⁩                        32.3 KB    disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS ⁨Google Chrome⁩           455.3 MB   disk2s2
                    (free space)                         13.0 GB    -

/dev/disk5 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +401.1 MB   disk5
   1:                  Apple_HFS ⁨Unity Hub 3.0.1⁩         401.0 MB   disk5s1

/dev/disk6 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.4 GB     disk6
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk6s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS ⁨Visual Studio⁩           2.1 GB     disk6s2
```

Comment: The Disk Utility can occasionally get confused and display incorrect information. I would encourage you to edit your question and include the output from the Terminal application command `diskutil list`.

Comment: edited with that terminal listing... i'm rather confused at how Disk Utility seems to show the duplicate `- Data` as containing the same amount of space

Comment: Since all the APFS volumes share the same APFS container, you should expect each volume to show the same amount of space (capacity). @Ezekiel's answer is probably correct. I would think you could use the Disk Utility to delete the second `Macintosh HD - Data` volume. This would be the volume showing 688 KB used. Right click on the volume name shown on the left side of the Disk Utility window and then select `Delete APFS Volume...`.

Comment: what happens if i don't delete it?

Comment: Nothing happens. The volume is using 0.000069% of your total disk space. I would at least rename the volume to something other than `Macintosh HD - Data`.

Comment: @ina /dev/disk1 line 7 is the same as "Macintosh HD (snapshot)" and the first "Macintosh HD" with the stack icon is a volume group, and isn't shown in this terminal output.

Answer (score 0):

- The first line in the sidebar, with the stack icon and labeled "Macintosh HD  (volumes)" is your installation.

  - Inside this, it contains "Macintosh HD" and "Macintosh HD - Data."

    - The greyed-out "Macintosh HD" is your system volume, but it's heavily protected.

      - The not-greyed-out "Macintosh HD (snapshot)" is what your system is actively using to work and operate, but is reset at boot.
    - "Macintosh HD - Data" contains any non-OS files. This is what your system uses to read your account information, installed apps, documents, files, etc.
- The next "Macintosh HD - Data" is likely from an old installation. You can view it in Finder, locate any files you'd like, then delete it in Disk Utility. **This is the only abnormal entry**

Comment: what happens if i don't delete it?

Comment: @ina It continues to be confusing and take up space - it's better to delete it so that next time you have to interact with this list you don't have to re-determine which one is which